# Google place API request denied issues

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to use Google places api to search the location. But Unfortunately I am getting only 1 message in responce is REQUEST DENIED. I have created new API key, but the API ACCESS Menu shows some warning icons as shown in below image does it created any issues or any other issues belonging to API key ?

Please let me know how to overcome this issue.... thanks in advance![image: enter code here]`

my request string is [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=)

Answer (score 3):

You should also never post your API Key on the Internet like in your request string above to prevent your key from being abused. Your API Key should be kept private like a password as any usage of your key will be logged against your account.

The request above works fine using my API Key, I would suggest generating another API Key on the API Access page of the APIs console. Also make sure that you have enabled the Places API under services, instructions are [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication).

The notification icons are there to notify you that you have not enabled billing on your account yet.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same error. the error was resolved by append `&sensor=false` at the end of API

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue, turns out using the key for Android applications (the one used for the maps API) is wrong. I needed to create a key for browser applications. Once I used the browser key instead of the Android key everything worked fine.